# Ubuntu removed by easybcd but is still appearing in boot menu

Tags: bootloader, easybcd

I have removed Ubuntu 12.10 from my system with easybcd and deleted the partition containing Ubuntu. Still when I start my system it gives me the option to load into either Windows 7 or Ubuntu. While loading into Ubuntu it throws errors, obviously because the files do not exist. In easybcd I see this format of my bootloader:

```
There are a total of 2 entries listed in the bootloader.

Default: Ubuntu
Timeout: Skipped
EasyBCD Boot Device: C:\

Entry #1
Name: Windows 7
BCD ID: {current}
Drive: C:\
Bootloader Path: \Windows\system32\winload.exe

Entry #2
Name: Ubuntu
BCD ID: {default}
Device: unknown
Bootloader Path: \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr
```

My question is how to remove this from my system so that when I switch it on I directly get to Windows 7.

Comment: did you installed ubuntu using `wubi`? then you should have removed from `add remove programs` wubi un installation doesn't need wiping partition.

Answer (score 0):

In EasyBCD 2.2:

- Click *Edit Boot Menu*.
- Select *Ubuntu*.
- Click *Delete*.
- You can optionaly click *Skip the boot menu*.

Save settings.